# LDAP on forward facing domains

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ldap

I am working on an app that allows the user to log in using AD, I am using essentially the same code as we use in our protected intranet, but this time the server is forward facing (or exposed to the internet)  My problem is when I logon with an invalid password, it obviously recognizes this, however when I go to get information from the LDAP connection such as group names it says the server does not exist.  below is my code and the stack trace error, these things are harder to figure out when deployed...

controller

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    string logon_user = model.UserName.ToString();
    string logon_password = model.Password.ToString();

    ConnHelper connhelper = new ConnHelper();
    string encryptedTicket = null;
    String adPath = "LDAP://dc1.servername.local/DC=servername,DC=local"; //Path to the LDAP directory server
    ADAuthorize adAuth = new  ADAuthorize(adPath);
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;

    try
    {
        if (true == adAuth.IsAuthenticated("dc1.servername.local", logon_user, logon_password))
        {
            string groups = adAuth.GetGroups();

            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.windows_id = logon_user;
            acc.password = logon_password;
            acc.igers_id = connhelper.GetiGersID(acc.windows_id);
            acc.email_address = acc.windows_id.ToString() + "@domain.com";
            acc.region = connhelper.IsNull(connhelper.GetRegionManager(acc.igers_id));
            acc.home_store_region = connhelper.IsNull(connhelper.GetHomeStoreRegion(acc.igers_id));
            acc.store_group = connhelper.IsNull(connhelper.GetStoreGroup(acc.igers_id));
            acc.home_store = connhelper.IsNull(connhelper.GetStore(acc.igers_id));
            acc.arr = connhelper.GetStores(acc.igers_id);
            //acc.home_store_phone = misc.IsNull(misc.GetHomeStorePhoneNumber("hzs"), "");
            acc.home_store_phone = connhelper.IsNull(connhelper.GetHomeStorePhoneNumber(acc.igers_id), "");
            acc.full_name = connhelper.IsNull(connhelper.GetFullName(acc.igers_id), "");
            //ErrorLabel.Text += "windows=" + misc.GetStore(acc.igers_id);

            //ErrorLabel.Text += "windows=" + acc.igers_id.ToString();

            //Add information to the session
            Session.Add("roles", groups);
            Session.Add("Account", acc);

            // Create the authentication ticket
            authTicket =
            new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,  // version
                acc.windows_id,
                DateTime.Now,
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
                false, groups);
            // Now encrypt the ticket.
            encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
            // Create a cookie and add the encrypted ticket to the cookie as data.
            HttpCookie authCookie =
                new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
            // Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection. 
            Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

            if (FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(acc.windows_id, false).EndsWith("Logout.aspx"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }

            // 
            //   Validate code this does the redirect to where you want the logged in person to go to.
            //
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
             ModelState.AddModelError("","Authentication failed, check username and password.");
             return View(model);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error authenticating. " + ex.Message);
        return View(model);
    }
   // return View(model);
}
```

The two parts of the model that I believe the problem exists in and the instantiate of the class:

```
class ADAuthorize
{
    private string _path;
    private string _filterAttribute;

    public ADAuthorize(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }
```

get users (this will return an invalid username /pass message, so I know its connecting.)

```
public bool IsAuthenticated(string domain, string username, string pwd)
{
    string domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, pwd);

    try
    {
        // Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication. 
        Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SAMAccountName");
        //search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
        if (null == result)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Update the new path to the user in the directory
        _path = result.Path;
        _filterAttribute = (String)result.Properties["SAMAccountName"][0];
        //_filterAttribute = (String)result.Properties["cn"][0];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is where it throws the error:

```
//Gets the Group
public string GetGroups()
{
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(_path);
    search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + _filterAttribute + ")";
    //search.Filter = "(cn=" + _filterAttribute + ")";
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
    StringBuilder groupNames = new StringBuilder();

    try
    {
        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
        int propertyCount = result.Properties["memberOf"].Count;
        String dn;
        int equalsIndex, commaIndex;

        for (int propertyCounter = 0; propertyCounter < propertyCount; propertyCounter++)
        {
            dn = (String)result.Properties["memberOf"][propertyCounter];

            equalsIndex = dn.IndexOf("=", 1);
            commaIndex = dn.IndexOf(",", 1);
            if (-1 == equalsIndex)
            {
                return null;
            }

            groupNames.Append(dn.Substring((equalsIndex + 1), (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1));
            groupNames.Append("|");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error obtaining group names. this is where the error is thrown " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
    }
    return groupNames.ToString();
}
```

My error and stack trace reads:

the specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

```
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) 
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() 
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() 
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList() 
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName) 
at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName) 
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.get_SearchRoot() 
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne) 
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne() 
at BoxCheckInApp.Controllers.ADAuthorize.GetGroups()
```

Again this works fine on a run from the IDE, I think my issue is the path,
but I don't know enough about AD to know what I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some digging I realized my problem was related to the directory searcher.

I added the following lines

```
 var searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(_path, _user, _pass);
 DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
```

and made  _user, and _pass private variables of ADAuthorize  which correspond to the username and password submitted, now it is connecting.